# Ubuntu 16.04 on Lenovo ThinkPad x260

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad, compatibility

Can someone tell me from experience if there are issues running Ubuntu 16.04 on a Lenovo ThinkPad x260? I'm about to order one with the intel i7 option. Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

Unfortunately there isn't really much information on which components exactly are  used. This is what i got:

- Processor: Intel Core i7-6500U-Prozessor (4 MB Cache, 3.10 GHz)
- Display: 12.5 FHD IPS (1920 x 1080) Non-Touch
- RAM: 16 GB DDR4 2133 MHz SoDIMM
- Video: Intel HD Graphics 520
- Security Chip: Software TPM and Hardware dTPM
- Keyboard: Englisch + backlit
- Pointing Device: UltraNav (TrackPoint and ClickPad) with finger print scanner.
- TPM Setting: Software TPM-capable
- Camera: 720p HD Camera
- Harddrive: 256 GB Solid-State-Laufwerk, SATA3 OPAL 2.0-fähig (I would replace this one)
- Expansion Slot: Smart Card Reader
- Battery: Lithium-Ionen-Battery with 3 Cells, 23,2 Wh, Front
- Battery Back: Lithium-Ionen-Battery with 6 Cells, 72 Wh, back
- Integrated Wi-Fi-/WLAN-Adapter: Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260 WLAN (2x2) + Bluetooth Version 4.1, vPro
  Display: X260 FHD IPS NT WW

Comment: You really need to specify what exact hardware components you're considering. Also, it should be noted that laptop manufacturers frequently vary their hardware based on supply unless you pay for a specific part/brand name.

Comment: Ubuntu generally works on most hardware, however the best way to find out is to try it.

Answer (score 1):

We can't tell by a laptop brand name as laptop manufacturers frequently switch out components based on supply, however, you can visit the list of [Ubuntu Certified Hardware](https://certification.ubuntu.com/certification/)